# C++ implicit/explicit template method specialization issue

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I have a problem with calling a function:

```
namespace Sort {

    enum Type {
        insertion, selection, merge
    };

    template <class Elem = int, class Container = std::vector<Elem>>
    void sort(std::shared_ptr<Container> vectorPointer,
              std::function<bool(Elem, Elem)> comparator = std::less<Elem>(),
              Type type = selection) {

        switch (type) {
            case insertion:
                insertionSort(vectorPointer, comparator);
            case selection:
                selectionSort(vectorPointer, comparator);
            case merge:
                mergeSort(vectorPointer, comparator);
        }
    }
}
```

When I call it as such:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> intVector;

Sort::sort(intVector);
```

Everything is OK, however if I start replacing the default parameters:

```
Sort::sort(intVector, std::less<int>(), merge);
```

I get an error message: `Candidate template ignored: could not match 'function' against 'less'`

Update:

I finally made it work - explicitly specializing the function call seemed to do the trick. Also, I didn't provide the namespace for the enum value.

```
Sort::sort<int, std::vector<int>>(intVector, std::less<int>(), Sort::merge)
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but is there a special reason you have a shared pointer to a container? It is rather uncommon and in many cases not needed.

Comment: As for your problem, I would personally generalize even *further* with the template types, and make the two first arguments templates as well. Or even make the function emulate just about all [standard algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) function which works on containers, and take two iterators as arguments instead of a container (and therefore drop the whole `Container` template argument). Also for example on how to use `std::less` using templates, why not look at [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)?

Comment: This was one of the very first pieces of code I've written in C++ and I'm refactoring it right now. Pointers were the very first thing that made things work to me. I'm aware of how painfully bad it is. I'll remove the pointers once I figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: I've updated the description - seems that explicitly specializing all template parameters made it work, but I have a new problem now. Thanks a lot for the input!

Comment: btw you have (probably unexpected) fallthrough in your switch statement.

Comment: I would still do my suggested change. It will increse the performance by not converting std::less signature, what for ints is unnoticable. But not for other types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 template <class Elem = int, class Container = std::vector<Elem>>
    void sort(std::shared_ptr<Container> vectorPointer,
              std::function<bool(Elem, Elem)> comparator = std::less<Elem>(),
              Type type = selection)
```

The comparator type depends on the template parameter Elem, so when the compiler performs template deduction rules it requires that the caller's provided value has a type that matches the type pattern of the argument.  Since 'less' and 'function' are not the same type, this function is not a valid match.

(Do not confuse the type deduction logic to be the same as the conversion sequence allowed when dealing with instances of these types.)

If you change your call to look like this it would work (though obviously you wouldn't want to do it due to the awful user experience):

```
Sort::sort(shV, std::function<bool(int, int)>(std::less<int>()), Sort::merge);
```

This way, the type of the 2nd argument is matching what the template expects. 
 The above example also solves your use of the 'merge' enumerator, which is in the Sort namespace and requires namespace qualification.

A small change to your signature, taking Compare as another template parameter, is a possibility:

```
template <class Elem = int, class Container = std::vector<Elem>, 
          class Compare = std::less<Elem>>
void sort(std::shared_ptr<Container> vectorPointer,
      Compare comparator = Compare(),
      Type type = selection) {
    switch (type) {
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great explanation. I wasn't aware that the signatures aren't matching. This definitely seems better from a user perspective.

Comment: @bartlomiej.n It also removes a level of indirection from the function call. `std::function` is *effectively* polymorphic, and there is virtual call overhead for invoking an `std::function`-wrapped callable (even though `std::function::operator()` is not itself virtual). By passing the callable directly as an argument with its own type, this indirection is not only removed, but there is a good chance that the compiler can even inline the callable invocation. For a function as simple as `std::less`, virtual call overhead for each comparison is not negligible!

Comment: @cdhowie I'll implement this change later on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `std::function<bool(Elem, Elem)> comparator` should be
`std::function<bool(const Elem&, const Elem&)>` or `std::function<bool(auto,auto)>` if you are using C++14.

Comment: Whereas you can use `auto` in lambda in C++14, parameter of the type of the  `std::function` cannot be `auto`.

Comment: What would this improve? I thought that letting the parameter by value would be the most efficient way

Comment: The thing is that std::less<T> takes (const T&,const T&). So, a cast will be made. And, for big types is better by const reference but not for basic types.